# Can't create multiple nested objects JS. "Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, debugging, object, error-handling

I have an object for a game. I want to nest 3+ objects inside that. However when I write the actual code I get an error saying:

> *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier*

on the first line of my second nested object.
Here's an example:

```
var ball = {
    stance : {
        player  :{boo: true},
        table   :{boo: false},
        computer:{boo: false}
    }
    paddelY : { // ERROR HERE <<<<
        1 : mouseY - height*0.05,
}}
```

Note: My real object is a lot longer but I shortened it to the above. The code here also throws an error.

I'm sure there is a simple fix! Thanks!

Comment: put a comma after the closing bracket of stance.

Comment: Missing comma between properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var ball = {
  stance: {
    player: { boo: true },
    table: { boo: false },
    computer: { boo: false }
  },
  paddelY: {
    1: mouseY - height * 0.05,
  }
}
```

you should add a comma (`,`) after stance

Comment: I don't think it needs to be said again ;)

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! Again, sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a comma between each key:value pair in an object literal.

You missed one between the line with the error on it and the previous line.

Comment: Haha! Thanks! Sorry that was really, a very stupid question!